# How do I use a blueprint in VEGA Conflict?

Tags: vega-conflict

I've completed a couple of blueprints in VEGA Conflict, but they don't appear in research. How can I use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blueprints are completed research, and appear at the bottom of the normal component lists in your Ship Factory. Simply refit or build a ship to use completed blueprints.